# retrieve secrets from Azure Key vault in azure databricks WITHOUT secret scope

Tags: python, azure, azure-databricks, azure-keyvault, azure-service-principal

I know, I can use secret scope in Azure Databricks and easly retrieve secrets/keys from Azure KeyVault.

But

I would like to try another way -> via a service principal.The service principal has permission to get/list secrets from my azure key vault.

My steps:

1. I create a cluster in azure databricks and install the libraries `azure-identity` and `azure-Keyvault`

I run the following code:

```
from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential as cs
from azure.keyvault.keys import KeyClient
kv_URI = "https://mykeyvault.vault.azure.net/"
TENANT_ID = 'yyyyy'
CLIENT_ID = 'zzzz'
CLIENT_SECRET = 'xxxxx'
credentials = cs(    
          tenant_id=TENANT_ID,
          client_id=CLIENT_ID,    
          client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET)    
secret_client = SecretClient(vault_url=kv_URI, credential=credentials)
secretlist=secret_client.get_secret("Mysecret")
```

but after some minutes I get time-out error.

Do you know how can I solve the problem?

Comment: When I ran your code in my environment, I got secret's value successfully like [this](https://i.imgur.com/SnQ2c8G.png). Could you please include your [cluster's settings](https://i.imgur.com/Dys57Os.png)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I registered one Azure AD application and added **API permission** as below:

[image]

In my key vault, I added **Get/List** secrets permissions for that service principal like this:

[image]

Now I created one data bricks cluster with below settings:

[image]

When I ran your code in my environment, I got **secret's value** successfully without any **time-out error** like below:

```py
from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential as cs
from azure.keyvault.keys import KeyClient
kv_URI = "https://mykeyvault.vault.azure.net/"
TENANT_ID = 'yyyyy'
CLIENT_ID = 'zzzz'
CLIENT_SECRET = 'xxxxx'
credentials = cs(    
          tenant_id=TENANT_ID,
          client_id=CLIENT_ID,    
          client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET)    
secret_client = SecretClient(vault_url=kv_URI, credential=credentials)
secretlist=secret_client.get_secret("Mysecret")
print(secretlist.value)
```

**Response:**

[image]

> but after some minutes I get time-out error.

In your case, try increasing the **size** of your Azure Data Bricks cluster and make sure to **restart** it.  If still the error persists, create new data bricks cluster with same settings that I mentioned above and repeat the process.